# How does read() system call in Linux implements waiting for input?

Tags: linux

From this question [Does read() wait in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313276/does-read-wait-in-linux) I've learned that `read()` blocks untill it see data in, e.g., pipe. But how it works internally? Does it check in cycle if first character of pipe or file descriptor is not `NULL` or some other character? How it knows when to stop waiting for data?

Comment: Does my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777192/how-does-linux-blocking-i-o-actually-work help?

Comment: Thank you, Dipstick, your answer brought some clarity to me, but how is the read_avail variable evaluated in macro given in your answer? And do I understand you correctly, that any read() call ends up interacting with some driver (which code's is given in your answer), like, e.g. filesystem driver?

Comment: "how it works" is a very big question. The exact machine code depend on the exact CPU you are using. `hat any read() call ends up interacting with some driver` `read` is (literally) a system call, it will end up interactive with kernel. You can write to `pipe` event to `eventfd`, there is only memory behind them.